# How to make the iCal in iPad to convert the received events in the proper time according the time zone of the device

Tags: ipad, outlook, timezone, icalendar

I am using DDay.iCal library to create an event with that should be in exact timezone:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:someId
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Central Europe Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20111002T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYHOUR=3;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:Central Europe Standard Time
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20110301T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:Central Europe Daylight Time
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Some Description
DTEND;TZID=Central Europe Standard Time:20120919T163000
DTSTAMP:20120913T082257Z
DTSTART;TZID=Central Europe Standard Time:20120919T160000
LOCATION:Some Location
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Some Summary
UID:1cf04d1c-2b5c-474c-86f4-108101da9b7a
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

As you can see the event is declared in Central European Standard Time for 16:00 - 16:30.

I am in another timezone - GMT + 2.

When I am adding the event to outlook in win7 - it is converted to my local time = from 17 to 17:30.

When I am adding it to a friend's Mac - it is converted to his local time.

When I am trying to add it in a Ipad which is set to the same timezone - GMT + 2, and with timezone support on, it is not converted but set to 16 - 16:30 and the timezone for the event is put to floating.

So my question is what I should change in the setup of the event to recognize it and converted to the right time?

Or maybe I should change something in the iPad settings.